# Visual Studio - Gerenciando publicação de dll registrada localmente do ambiente de homologação e produção

Tags: c#, assembly, dll, visual-studio-2017

Estou trabalhando com uma Dll do banco Itaú(**itauCripto.dll**), a documentação exige que ela seja registrada localmente na máquina que está rodando a aplicação.
Então coloquei a Dll dentro da pasta

> %systemroot%\SysWoW64\

e registrei ela pelo CMD como administrador usando

> %systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32 itaucripto.dll

Adicionei a referencia dela dentro do meu projeto no Visual Studio 2017 como COM Reference e utilizei ela normalmente dentro do projeto.

O fato é que na minha máquina está rodando corretamente sem nenhum problema, porém quando vou aplicar essa alteração no servidor de produção a aplicação não encontra a Dll.

A parte do registro fiz exatamente a mesma coisa que descrevi acima no servidor de produção porém quando publico o projeto e jogo no servidor de produção ele não encontra a referencia.

Notei que apesar de quando seleciono a Dll no painel de Add Reference ela estar apontando para a pasta *%systemroot%\SysWoW64* no meu projeto a referência fica apontando para a pasta bin do projeto (**WebApplication\obj\Debug\Interop.Itaucripto.dll**).

Não sei se quando o visual studio publica o projeto ele está se perdendo nesse caminho.

Alguém pode dizer o que esta errado ou como posso tornar esse caminho relativo?

Comment: O pool da sua aplicação do IIS está rodando em 64bits tbm?

Comment: Esta em 64bits, estava desabilitado para rodar em 32bits, mudei agora pra true a configuração e vou testar, pq tenho quase certeza que a dll é de 32 bits. Como estou usando na minha máquina o iis express acredito que não dê problema, mas como no servidor as configurações são diferentes pode ser um caminho.

Comment: Se for o caso de ser 32bits, existe diferença no registro... Teria que ser feito pelo diretório `%systemroot%\System32`.

Comment: @Bruno acho que na verdade o problema estava mesmo relacionado a plataforma. Alterei o pool para permitir 32bits, mas também alterei a propriedade da referência no projeto para Embed Interop Types = False. Isso fez com que a Dll fosse publicada junto com o projeto. Funcionou perfeitamente, vou publicar a resposta completa para ajudar quem precisar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em alguns casos, quando você adiciona uma referência para uma Dll COM compilada para código nativo (no caso Itaucripto.dll), o Visual Studio gera uma Dll intermediária para acelerar a comunicação entre o seu programa (que é bytecode .Net, ou seja, não é nativo) e a Dll nativa (nesse caso Interop.Itaucripto.dll).

Possíveis motivos do seu programa não encontrar a dll nativa:

- O programa está sendo executado por um usuário diferente do usuário que registrou a Dll. A Dll deve ser registrada por um usuário admin, executando o regsvr32 como administrador, de forma que fique visível para todos os usuários ou o programa deve ser executado pelo mesmo usuário que registou a Dll. (Obs: Programas que rodam no IIS são tipicamente executados pelo usuário do IIS, a menos que sejam configurados para usar outro usuário.)
- O programa está sendo executado como um processo 64 bits, mas a dll nativa é 32 bits. Nesse caso é necessário configurar o programa para executar como 32 bits. Isso pode ser feito nas configurações do projeto principal (o .exe ou o website) ou nas configurações do IIS (se for um website).

Comment: Legal não sabia exatamente o que acontecia quando o VS compilava essa Dll.

Comment: Legal não sabia exatamente o que acontecia quando o VS compilava essa Dll. Com relação a plataforma o projeto é configurado para rodar nas duas plataformas, porém como o servidor de hospedagem é 64b eu registrei a Dll na pasta SysWoW64. Com relação aos usuários eu tenho permissão de admin no servidor, não sei se preciso fornecer permissão específica para o IIS nessa Dll, vou procurar a respeito disso.

Comment: @RicardoCardoso. Apesar dos nomes, a pasta SysWoW64 é onde o Windows guarda as versões 32 bits das dlls 64 bits que ficam na pasta System32. Isso permite que ele execute programas 32 bits, mesmo o sistema sendo 64 bits.

Comment: Se a .dll é nativa e foi compilada em 32 bits, não importa em qual pasta você registrou, a .dll continua sendo 32 bits.

Comment: @RicardoCardoso se você achou que a resposta foi boa, por favor dê um voto positivo (flechinha pra cima no canto superior esquerdo da resposta).

Comment: acho que na verdade o problema estava mesmo relacionado a plataforma. Alterei o pool para permitir 32bits, mas também alterei a propriedade da referência no projeto para Embed Interop Types = False. Isso fez com que a Dll fosse publicada junto com o projeto. Funcionou perfeitamente, vou publicar a resposta completa para ajudar quem precisar.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade o problema estava relacionado a plataforma da Dll e no Pool da aplicação.

Registrei a Dll na pasta *system32* ao invés de *SysWoW64*

Alterei o Pool para permitir aplicações 32 bits

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas também alterei a propriedade da referência no projeto para Embed Interop Types = False.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso fez com que a propriedade Copy Local mudasse para True e dessa maneira a Dll fosse publicada junto com o projeto.

Funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: A dll, sendo copiada junto ao projeto o sistema estaria utilizando a dll da propria pasta não a da System, não é isso?

Comment: Pensei isso tbm, porém quando eu desfaço o registro da dll na pasta System32 a aplicação lança um erro pois a dll não está registrada. Tentei o contrário tbm, sem colocar a dll no pacote e tbm dá erro pois a dll não é encontrada nesse caso, hehehe